# Can I discuss someone else's question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, comments

I wanted to post a question but I decided to search if it had been asked before on information security. I found a very similar question with a good answer but I wanted some clarification so I posted a comment on the answer. The person who had given the answer replied and told me that I should not discuss the question there and instead ask a new question.

So what should I do next time?

Comment: For the future: Links to the posts in question would be helpful. If you say "some clarification", that could be "What do you mean by ..." or "Does that also apply to ...?" - which are both very different

Answer (score 4):

If you want clarification on an answer, asking in a comment is what you should do.

However, if you want to extend the scope of the answer or ask about how the answer applies in another context, then it is likely that you are asking a separate question.